USB passthrough in Android emulator on MacOS M1 failing to acquire exclusive access
I am trying to get my Android emulator to see the Wi-Fi dongle or my Ethernet dongle connected over USB to the Macbook Pro M1. I tried the following methods:
Command:
./emulator -avd MyTestEmulator -gpu host -qemu -device usb-ehci,id=ehci -device usb-host,bus=ehci.0,vendorid=0x0bda,productid=0x8153

Output:
2024-05-30 18:10:50.224 qemu-system-aarch64[21796:116971] Acquiring USB Exclusive access for device: <vendorID: 0xbda, productID: 0x8153>
2024-05-30 18:10:50.508 qemu-system-aarch64[21796:116971] Service authorization failed with error with return code: -536870202
2024-05-30 18:10:50.511 qemu-system-aarch64[21796:116971] Error creating device: Failed to create IOUSBHostObject.

Things I have tried so far: Tried starting emulator with this command:
./qemu-system-aarch64 -avd TestEmulator -usb-passthrough vendorid=0x0bda,productid=0x8153

Says
qemu-system-aarch64: -device usb-host,bus=ehci.0,vendorid=0x0bda,productid=0x8153: 'usb-host' is not a valid device model name

I searched for answers, for Linux machines, we need to give write access for this USB port in a udev rule. But could not find the equivalent one for MacOS running on Arm M1.
